# Yii2 Rest URL Routing for Regular Controllers

Tags: rest, yii2, yii-url-manager

How is it possible to extend **yii\rest\UrlRule** in a way I can rewrite rules for actions of a controller? For example, I want to generate the following URIs:

```
/user/[username]
/user/keywords
/user/keyword/[key1]/[key2]/[...]
...
```

Every above actions are rendering their own view too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend `yii\rest\UrlRule`. Just add your rules to routes of `UrlManager` by putting them on `extraPatterns` property of `yii\rest\UrlRule`.

For example suppose You defined a `list` action in your controller:

```
class BarController extends Controller
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Foo';

    public function actionList()
    {
        return ['id' => 1];
    }
}
```

Then in configuration file add extra route:

```
<?php
// some configs are here
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => [
                'v1/bar',
            ],
            'extraPatterns' => [
                'GET list' => 'list',
            ],
        ],
    ],
], 
// and some other configs are here
```

Now you can browse the api with `/v1/bars/list`. Read [Yii2 Documentations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html) for more examples.

Comment: It doesn't work for my case. Actually, I just want to beautify my URLs like rest and use the normal controller instead of ActiveController to represent output.

Comment: What's your problem? `ActiveController` is extended from `Controller` and has all it parent behaviors.

Comment: Hi how can I add date token? I have also posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73578796/6854117). Can you pl check it?

Answer (score 0):

you must change the extends of Controller in ActiveController

```
class ArticleController extends ActiveController
```